# What should be the Generic for the concrete class if the super class has a bounded generic

Tags: java, generics

What should be the generic part of the definition of the Subclass

I have a super class I don't want to modify the generic part in the definition of Sort

```
public class Sort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
  public abstract void sort(List<T> thingToSort);
}
```

I want to write

```
public void HeapSort"<>" extends Sort"<>" {

}
```

what should be kept in generic part of definition of HeapSort

and somewhere in main

```
HeapSort sort = new HeapSort<>(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)));
```

Comment: `class HeapSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Sort<T>`

Comment: I suppose you meant `public abstract class Sort`, `public class HeapSort` and `HeapSort sort = new HeapSort<>(); sort.sort(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to propagate `T` with its bounds to the extending class:

```
public void HeapSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Sort<T> { ... }
```

This effectively defines a type argument `T` on `HeapSort` that is used to instantiate the type argument on the superclass `Sort`.

You can then create a new `HeapSort` like so:

```
HeapSort<Integer> sort = new HeapSort<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
```